# How should I use variables in OpenGL without violating encapsulation

Tags: opengl

I am learning OpenGL but I am a little confused about the way how variables are used. In many example codes written in C++, the variables are used as global variables. But I do not think it is desirable for us to use too many global variables in the program. So I am wondering how can I use variables without violating encapsulation? Or should I use a singleton to record all the variables such as the models?

Comment: Example code is meant to be exactly that: examples. Unless they are examples of good programming practice, examples will generally not take the time to exhibit good programming practices, especially if doing so would only complicate the code. So take the examples for what they are: showing how functionality works. It's your job as a programmer to learn how the functionality works and then integrate it into whatever application you're writing in whatever way serves what you feel is good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In many example codes written in C++, the variables are used as global variables

This sound like you're reading examples written using the GLUT framework. That the variables are global is a direct result of GLUTs design to be a minimalistic framework, that's meant for simple tests and techdemos. You should not use GLUT for serious applications.

GLUT is not part of OpenGL. It's a 3rd party library and there's no requirement to use it in any way when it comes to OpenGL. In fact it's highly recommended you don't use it.

OpenGL itself can be used from encapsulated code just fine. Look for OpenGL examples that use the Qt framework. IMHO the way Qt implements OpenGL widgets and context encapsulation is suboptimal (only recently I've run into serious limitations), but if you're an beginner you'll hardly notice that.

Comment: I see. These days I am reading examples using GLUT and I had thought GLUT was a part of the library OpenGL. In most examples, the variables are global variables and for others the variables are hard coded. Thank you very much for your help. I will try to read some examples using opengl.